# How do I get a user from their discord tag in Discord JDA?

Tags: discord-jda

Is there a way to find someone's id from their discord tag? Note: They are in a certain guild that I have the ID of if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean "Name#1234" with the *discord tag*:

Until [this feature request](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1574) has been implemented by discord you have to use a different approach. If you have all members cached you can simply use [Guild#getMemberByTag](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMemberByTag(java.lang.String)). Otherwise you have to use [Guild#retrieveMembersByPrefix](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#retrieveMembersByPrefix(java.lang.String,int)) and hope that there aren't more than 100 users with the same name:

```java
String name = tag.substring(0, tag.lastIndexOf('#'));
guild.retrieveMembersByPrefix(name, 100).onSuccess(members -> {
  Member member = members.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getUser().getAsTag().equals(tag))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
  if (member != null) {
    // use member here, it should be the member with that specific tag
  } else {
    // there are either more than 100 users with the same name or the member is not int he server
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! There definitely isn't going to be 100 users with the same username on my server, although, is there a way to cache all members when the bot starts?

Comment: Just throwing this out there; remember to accept answers that solve your question.